# using white spaces in variable with powershell using msdeploy

Tags: variables, powershell, escaping, whitespace, msdeploy

I have a problem with white spaces in variable using powershell and msdeploy.
This is what I need:

```
$IdConnectionString = "Hello World"
$msdeploy = "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" 

cd 'C:\Windows\DtlDownloads\WebServices\WebServices\IdService\_PublishedWebsites\IdService_Package'

[System.Collections.ArrayList]$msdeployArgs = [string[]]@(
  "-verb:sync",
  "-source:package='IdService.zip'",
  "-verbose",
  "-dest:auto"
  "-setParam:Environment=$IdConnectionString"
  )

& $msdeploy $msdeployArgs
```

This is the error message:

```
msdeploy.exe : Error: Unrecognized argument '"-setParam:Environment=Werk niet"'. All arguments must begin with "-".
At C:\Windows\DtlDownloads\WebServices\WebServices\IdService\_PublishedWebsites\IdService\Deployment\IdServiceWSDeploy.ps1:23 
char:1
+ & $msdeploy $msdeployArgs
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Error: Unrecogn...begin with "-".:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Error count: 1.
```

This also works:

```
$msdeploy = "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" 

cd 'C:\Windows\DtlDownloads\WebServices\WebServices\IdService\_PublishedWebsites\IdService_Package'

[System.Collections.ArrayList]$msdeployArgs = [string[]]@(
  "-verb:sync",
  "-source:package='IdService.zip'",
  "-verbose",
  "-dest:auto"
  )


& $msdeploy $msdeployArgs -setParam:Environment=`'Werk niet`'
```

But I really need the variable for automatic deployment. Normal the `$IdConnectionString` variable is defined in another configuration script used with Release Management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may need to use Start-Process like this:

```
$IdConnectionString = "Hello World"
$msdeploy = "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" 

$msdeployArgs = @(
  "-verb:sync",
  "-source:package='IdService.zip'",
  "-verbose",
  "-dest:auto"
  "-setParam:Environment=`"$IdConnectionString`""
)

Start-Process $msdeploy -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList $msdeployArgs
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
$msdeploy = "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" 
$IdConnectionString = "Hello World"

$msdeployArgs = @{
  verb = 'sync'
  source = "package='IdService.zip'"
  verbose = $true
  dest = 'auto'
  setParam = "Environment='$IDConnectionString'"
  }

  Invoke-Expression "& '$msdeploy' $(&{$args}@msdeployArgs)"
```

Edit: Most of you problem seems to revolve around quoting. After looking at the msdeploy docs, I think the simplest solution would be to simply build the command in an expandable here string:

$IdConnectionString = "Hello World"
$msdeploy = "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe"

```
$cmd = @"
& '$msdeploy' -verb:Sync -Source:package='IDService.zip' -verbose -dest:auto -setParam:Environment='$IdConnectionString'
"@

invoke-expression $cmd
```

I can't really duplicate your environment for testing, but basically you just need to find the the command string that works from a command prompt, then duplicate that in the here string, and invoke it.

Comment: I am going to try this. I will keep you posted

Comment: This is the error:
C:\Program : The term 'C:\Program' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe System.Collections.Dic ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Program:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: $msdeployArgs = @{
  verb = 'sync'
  source = "package='Ordina.RvR.IdService.zip'"
  verbose = $true
  dest = 'auto'
  setParam = "Environment='$IDConnectionString'"
  }

 Invoke-Expression "& '$msdeploy' $(&{$args}@msdeployArgs)"

But is does not work :(

Comment: There is no reason to use Invoke-Expression here.  Invoking commands is simple in PowerShell and Invoke-Expression adds extra complexity that gets in the way of the simpler solution.

Comment: @Jason Shirk - fair enough. If you will post the simpler solution, I will vote for it and withdraw the answer.